# Windows 1809 update always fails with 0x80070490

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, windows-10-upgrade, windows-10-v1803, windows-10-v1809

[image]

It always fails at exactly at "Status: Preparing to install - 80%".

I have tried everything I could possibly think of:

```
DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Scanhealth
sfc /scannow
```

Removing c:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution (https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2223969-1809-update-error-at-install-0x80070490?page=1#entry-8486582) or "Windows Repair" (https://www.tweaking.com/content/page/windows_repair_all_in_one.html).

The WindowsUpdate.log I get with `Get-WindowsUpdateLog` doesn't contain anything useful either. The last messages are:

```
[...]
2020-03-29 16:05:06.3603049 5044  13616 DownloadManager Downloading from http://tlu.dl.delivery.mp.microsoft.com/filestreamingservice/files/3b376681-46d3-4369-a7f1-3af38277adc8?P1=1585512870&P2=402&P3=2&P4=aCBW3EDTml8B3XQaaUTnexmcly%2bmH%2byssGFFFtbhnYX8QDW1RHpyPd4Opi2NSoMTypqeNB6%2btIJcpPn8xt0hvw%3d%3d to C:\WINDOWS\SoftwareDistribution\Download\9a7a8eff8aff2a1fe2261d6b7d7a8929\amd64_Microsoft-OneCore-ApplicationModel-Sync-Desktop-FOD-Package_rs4_release.17134.1304.180410-1804.cab (full file).
2020-03-29 16:05:06.3604000 5044  13616 DownloadManager Created download job 251FE845-A47A-400C-B811-5176752184E0; memory stream: No.
2020-03-29 16:05:06.3750224 5044  13616 DownloadManager New download job {251FE845-A47A-400C-B811-5176752184E0} for UpdateId 6EA6D7FF-D374-4148-AED4-0830478A03FC.1
2020-03-29 16:05:06.7986064 5044  13616 DownloadManager Update the URLs for DO Job 251FE845-A47A-400C-B811-5176752184E0 - Update 6EA6D7FF-D374-4148-AED4-0830478A03FC.1
2020-03-29 16:05:07.1322490 5044  13616 DownloadManager Download job 251FE845-A47A-400C-B811-5176752184E0 resumed.
2020-03-29 16:09:14.2221009 5044  5340  DownloadManager DO job {251FE845-A47A-400C-B811-5176752184E0} completed successfully, updateId = 6EA6D7FF-D374-4148-AED4-0830478A03FC.1
2020-03-29 16:09:15.7372836 5044  13616 DownloadManager Queueing update 6EA6D7FF-D374-4148-AED4-0830478A03FC.1 for download handler request generation.
2020-03-29 16:09:15.8376936 5044  7388  DownloadManager Generating download request for update 6EA6D7FF-D374-4148-AED4-0830478A03FC.1.
2020-03-29 16:09:15.9092473 5044  7388  DownloadManager Calling into handler 0xc to generate download request for update 6EA6D7FF-D374-4148-AED4-0830478A03FC.1.
2020-03-29 16:09:15.9389298 5044  6840  Misc            Validating signature for C:\WINDOWS\SoftwareDistribution\Download\9a7a8eff8aff2a1fe2261d6b7d7a8929\DesktopDeployment.cab with dwProvFlags 0x00000080:
2020-03-29 16:09:15.9770877 5044  6840  Misc             Microsoft signed: Yes
2020-03-29 16:09:16.0383498 5044  6840  Handler         Using the update's service stack dll file 'C:\WINDOWS\SoftwareDistribution\Download\9a7a8eff8aff2a1fe2261d6b7d7a8929\Metadata\UpdateAgent.dll' 
2020-03-29 16:09:16.9296167 5044  7388  Handler         UUP GDR: Event Fired: TimeOut
2020-03-29 16:09:16.9296380 5044  7388  DownloadManager GenerateDownloadRequest returned WU_E_OPERATIONINPROGRESS for update 6EA6D7FF-D374-4148-AED4-0830478A03FC.1.
2020-03-29 16:15:45.7517899 5044  6840  DownloadManager Subscribing to GDR Retry due to async handler trigger.
2020-03-29 16:15:46.1669676 5044  7388  DownloadManager Generating download request for update 6EA6D7FF-D374-4148-AED4-0830478A03FC.1.
2020-03-29 16:15:46.2460245 5044  7388  DownloadManager Calling into handler 0xc to generate download request for update 6EA6D7FF-D374-4148-AED4-0830478A03FC.1.
2020-03-29 16:15:46.2460364 5044  7388  Handler         *FAILED* [80070490] UUP GDR: Completed
2020-03-29 16:15:46.2523025 5044  7388  DownloadManager *FAILED* [80070490] GDR
2020-03-29 16:15:46.5577866 5044  7388  DownloadManager *FAILED* [80070490] Error occurred while downloading update 6EA6D7FF-D374-4148-AED4-0830478A03FC.1; notifying dependent calls.
2020-03-29 16:15:46.6679550 5044  13616 DownloadManager * END * Download Call Complete Call 4 for caller UpdateOrchestrator has completed; signaling completion.
2020-03-29 16:15:46.6685862 5044  13616 Agent           Effective power state: AC; IsOnAC: Yes.
2020-03-29 16:15:46.6685996 5044  13616 IdleTimer       WU operation (DL.UpdateOrchestrator, operation # 425) stopped; does use network; is not at background priority
2020-03-29 16:15:46.6686071 5044  13616 Agent           Released network PDC reference for callId {7C31AE7B-B2E8-4E9D-9FAE-E69C5EEB4AA5}; ActivationID: 425
2020-03-29 16:15:46.6689426 5044  5276  ComApi          *RESUMED* Download ClientId = UpdateOrchestrator
2020-03-29 16:15:46.6689474 5044  5276  ComApi          Download call complete (succeeded = 0, succeeded with errors = 0, failed = 1, cancelled = 0, unaccounted = 0)
2020-03-29 16:15:46.6689588 5044  5276  ComApi          ClientId = UpdateOrchestrator: Exit code = 0x00000000; Call error code = 0x80240022
2020-03-29 16:15:46.6689608 5044  5276  ComApi          * END *   Download ClientId = UpdateOrchestrator
2020-03-29 16:15:46.6689667 5044  5276  Agent           WU client calls back to download call {7C31AE7B-B2E8-4E9D-9FAE-E69C5EEB4AA5} with code Call complete and error 0x80070490
2020-03-29 16:15:46.6693800 5044  5796  ComApi          Download call complete (succeeded = 0, succeeded with errors = 0, failed = 1, cancelled = 0, unaccounted = 0)
2020-03-29 16:15:46.6693911 5044  5796  ComApi          * END *   All federated downloads have completed. ClientId = UpdateOrchestrator (cV = Kuodo0a890eUtjBr.3.1)
2020-03-29 16:15:46.6823141 5044  13616 DownloadManager DynamicDownloadDataFetcher Refresh Svc: {8B24B027-1DEE-BABB-9A95-3517DFB9C552}
2020-03-29 16:15:46.6823196 5044  13616 DownloadManager *FAILED* [8024000C] DynamicDownloadDataFetcher Refresh complete
```

It's super frustrating. Any hope to get the update installed without reinstalling Windows?

Comment: Try running all the steps in:  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971058    . Restart when done and test.

Comment: Try running *Settings > Update & Security > Troubleshoot* and click under "Get up and running" the link of  "Windows Update - Resolve problems that prevent you from updating Windows".

Comment: This [tool](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/upgrade/setupdiag) is invaluable to diagnose your problem.  The error log indicates a great deal more then you realize.

Comment: @harrymc That was the first I tried (and did it multiple times). Everytimes says cannot find anything wrong

Comment: @John I tried the first step (`Reset-WindowsUpdate.ps1`) ... no success. Currently running through all the points in `ResetWUEng.cmd` ... but don't have too much hope either since I've reset so many things already. This seems to be a pretty hard nut to crack :( :( It has to be possible to figure out WHAT is causing the failure, right?

Comment: At this point, run a Windows 10 Repair Install from the Media Creation link.  Use the second link, run in place, and at the appropriate point, Keep Everything.   https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10    .. Assuming this works (normally does) it will put you at V1909.

Comment: @John Absolutely insane how Windows can be that broken. Wow, how I love apt (sorry I have to say that). Did resort to your second suggestion and reinstalled, that worked. (although having lots of bloatware on my system now)

Comment: @divB - Before you resort to a in-place repair.  I high recommend using that tool I suggested.  I have a 100% success rate figuring out the reason feature updates cannot be installed using that tool.

Comment: @Ramhound Thank you, I upvoted for your response because it was a useful attempt (and might be useful in future) but unfortunately did not work either: The log file it created was zero bytes. However, I assume it would have not shown much more than the log file I posted (obtained via `Get-WindowsUpdateLog`.

Comment: @divB - I should have clarified how the tool works.  You actually have to attempt the upgrade.  Since Windows Update is failing to even download the feature update, your system never attempts it, I didn't realize that until just now. So my suggestion would be to download a 1809 ISO directly from Microsoft, mount the ISO, and manually perform the upgrade to 1809.  Of course 1809 is quickly reaching end of life, so you might want to use 1909 instead, otherwise you only have around 6 months before the upgrade to 1909 will be required. It absolutely would have helped if your system made an attempt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since other suggestions did not work, the next step is to run a Windows 10 Repair Install from the Media Creation link. Use the second link, run in place, and at the appropriate point, Keep Everything.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Assuming this works (normally does) it will put you at V1909.